# Weird artefacts/pixels in QGIS-created shaded relief map

Tags: qgis, dem, shaded-relief

I'm working with 30m SRTM data on an terrain map of Cuba. I downloaded the necessary DEM files, merged them and went on to create the shaded relief map in QGIS 2.8 using Raster > Analyze > DEM (Terrain models).

I tried a bunch of different settings but I always get this same result:

[image: Terrain map as seen in QGIS 2.8]

Not finding what was wrong (I first thought it was a problem of converting degrees to meters), I double-checked the .tif file in Aperçu and it looks just fine there:

[image: Terrain map as seen in Aperçu]

To clarify, those are the same file, loaded in QGIS as a raster and simply opened in OS X Aperçu. Any ideas what the source of the problem is in QGIS?

EDIT: Here's what the gdalinfo command returns about the image:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: Cuba30Terrain.tif
Cuba30Terrain.tif.aux.xml
Size is 39601, 18001
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (-85.000138888888884,24.000138888888888)
Pixel Size = (0.000277777777778,-0.000277777777778)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
 Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( -85.0001389,  24.0001389) ( 85d 0' 0.50"W, 24d 0' 0.50"N)
Lower Left  ( -85.0001389,  18.9998611) ( 85d 0' 0.50"W, 18d59'59.50"N)
Upper Right ( -73.9998611,  24.0001389) ( 73d59'59.50"W, 24d 0' 0.50"N)
Lower Right ( -73.9998611,  18.9998611) ( 73d59'59.50"W, 18d59'59.50"N)
Center      ( -79.5000000,  21.5000000) ( 79d30' 0.00"W, 21d30' 0.00"N)
Band 1 Block=39601x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
  Min=1.000 Max=255.000 
  Minimum=1.000, Maximum=255.000, Mean=180.682, StdDev=7.098
  NoData Value=0
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=255
    STATISTICS_MEAN=180.68177132469
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=1
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=7.0979989753955
```

Comment: What does gdalinfo tell about the image?

Comment: @user30184 I edited my initial question with what the gdalinfo command returns.